# unclosable windows when sending excel pdf to mail

Tags: excel, email, pdf, window, vba

So I found a macro exporting an excel sheet to pdf, sending that pdf to a email address with outlook, then closing outlook (if opened by the macro) and deleting the pdf file.

I found the code which I enclosed underneath right [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/710212-visual-basic-applications-code-convert-excel-pdf-email-attachment.html)

```
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim i As Long
  Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object

  ' Not sure for what the Title is
  Title = "DUTY"

  ' Define PDF filename
  PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
  If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
  PdfFile = PdfFile & ".pdf"

  ' Export activesheet as PDF
  With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With

  ' Use already open Outlook if possible
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0

  ' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Prepare e-mail
    .Subject = Title
    .To = "info@feam.be" ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
    .Body = "Zie bijlage voor de duty report"
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile

    ' Try to send
    On Error Resume Next
    .Send
    Application.Visible = True
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
    Else
      MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

  End With

  ' Delete PDF file
  Kill PdfFile

  ' Quit Outlook if it was created by this code
  If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

  ' Release the memory of object variable
  Set OutlApp = Nothing
```

It works like a charm EXCEPT for the fact that when done, there are two Excel windows open (not sheets, just the application without any sheets open in it), that I can't seem to close.

I tried fixing it by adding

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close True

Application.Quit
```

...at the end of the code, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Has anyone got experience with this and hopefully know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and found no error in it. However, I found no need for your various calls to make applications visible. Therefore I omitted them. Perhaps they were the reason for your experience. Below is the code I tested.

```
Sub SendPDF()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim IsCreated As Boolean
    Dim PdfFile As String, Fn() As String
    Dim Title As String

'    ' Define PDF filename
    Fn = Split(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".")
    Fn(UBound(Fn)) = "pdf"
    PdfFile = Join(Fn, ".")

    ' this code will not work if the file name includes a period:-
'    PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
'    i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
'    If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
'    PdfFile = PdfFile & ".pdf"

    ' Export activesheet as PDF
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:=PdfFile, _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    ' Use already open Outlook if possible
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        IsCreated = True
    End If
'    OutApp.Visible = True             ' you don't need this to be visible
                                       ' unless you want to edit before sending
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' This is the tile of the email
    Title = "Duty report " & Date

    ' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
    With OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        .Subject = Title
        .To = "info@feam.be" ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
        .Body = "Zie bijlage voor de duty report"
        .Attachments.Add PdfFile

        On Error Resume Next
        .Send                           ' try to send

    '    Application.Visible = True     ' appears not required

        If Err Then
            Title = "An error occurred." & vbCr & _
                    "The email wasn't sent."
        Else
            Title = "The mail was prepared successfuly." & vbCr & _
                    "It is now in your outbox."
        End If
        MsgBox Title, vbInformation, "Execution report"
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Delete PDF file
    Kill PdfFile

    ' Quit Outlook if it was created by this code
    If IsCreated Then OutApp.Quit

    ' Release the memory of OutApp object variable
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will find that I made a few changes, including adding the date to the subject ("Title") which is in the nature of a suggestion, since you didn't know what it was for. Please read the comments I added to the code.

To my own surprise I couldn't make your method of opening Outlook work. My code failed every time when I didn't have Outlook already open. I referred to Ron de Bruin and found no fault with your code. In the end I left it as is. In my tests, when Outlook was not running, the object `OutApp` could not be set and led to the notification "Outlook is trying to recover your information" followed by failure of the next reference to `OutApp`. If this functionality is important to you it might be worth a separate question. Otherwise I suggest to modify the code to issue a message when Outlook isn't running instead of trying to create the object. FYI, I tested with Excel 2010.

Comment: I tried you code, and now I don't get the unclosable windows. I read your comments and deleted those lines indeed. It's not actually necessary to open Outlook, since it's permanently open here.

Thanks alot!